# stop bar plots from overlapping in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to have two different datasets positioned each other, like that when you have position="dodge" (area of erosion and deposition), and then plot two line graphs showing erosion and deposition rates for each reach. Right now, the area of deposition and erosion bar graphs are overlapping each other. I am able to get them to stack if I reorganise the data and plot it with geom_bar(position="dodge") (see right at the bottom), but in the process, my rates data get represented as a bar as well, which I do not want. Thank you in advance.

This is my current graph:
[image: here] 
I wish to get something like this: 
[image]

```
EroDepoStuff <- tibble::tribble(
                 ~Reach, ~Total.lateral.erosion, ~Total.lateral.deposition, ~Lateral.erosion.rate, ~Lateral.deposition.rate,
              "Reach 1",              44.818334,                  17.400127,             4.4818334,                1.7400127,
              "Reach 2",              91.865675,                   91.39827,             9.1865675,                 9.139827,
              "Reach 3",                7.40573,                  16.654819,              0.740573,                1.6654819,
              "Reach 4",              25.214554,                  52.084122,             2.5214554,                5.2084122,
                  "All",             169.304293,                 177.537338,            16.9304293,               17.7537338
              )

EroDepoGraph <- ggplot(EroDepoStuff,aes(x=Reach,group=4)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=Total.lateral.erosion,fill="Lateral erosion"),position="dodge",stat="identity") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Lateral.erosion.rate*10,colour="Lateral erosion rate")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Lateral.erosion.rate*10,colour="Lateral erosion rate")) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=Total.lateral.deposition,fill="Lateral deposition"),position="dodge",stat="identity")+
  geom_line(aes(y=Lateral.deposition.rate*10,colour="Lateral deposition rate")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Lateral.deposition.rate*10,colour="Lateral deposition rate")) +
  labs(y="Area (sq km)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Lateral erosion"="skyblue4","Lateral deposition"="blue")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("Lateral erosion rate"="violetred3","Lateral deposition rate"="tan1")) +
  labs(color = "", fill = "") 


#adding second axis 
EroDepoGraph <- EroDepoGraph + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10,name = expression(paste("Rate (sq km/yr)"))))


#formatting axes
EroDepoGraph <- EroDepoGraph + theme(
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_text(size=11),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size=11,angle=90,hjust=1),
  legend.position="bottom", 
  legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.1, "cm"),
  plot.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold")
)
EroDepoGraph

reOrganisedData <- ReorderedData <- tibble::tribble(
                      ~Reach,     ~Value,                      ~Type,
                   "Reach 1",  44.818334,    "Total lateral erosion",
                   "Reach 2",  91.865675,    "Total lateral erosion",
                   "Reach 3",    7.40573,    "Total lateral erosion",
                   "Reach 4",  25.214554,    "Total lateral erosion",
                       "All", 169.304293,    "Total lateral erosion",
                   "Reach 1",  17.400127, "Total.lateral.deposition",
                   "Reach 2",   91.39827, "Total.lateral.deposition",
                   "Reach 3",  16.654819, "Total.lateral.deposition",
                   "Reach 4",  52.084122, "Total.lateral.deposition",
                       "All", 177.537338, "Total.lateral.deposition",
                   "Reach 1",  4.4818334,     "Lateral erosion rate",
                   "Reach 2",  9.1865675,     "Lateral erosion rate",
                   "Reach 3",   0.740573,     "Lateral erosion rate",
                   "Reach 4",  2.5214554,     "Lateral erosion rate",
                       "All", 16.9304293,     "Lateral erosion rate",
                   "Reach 1",  1.7400127,  "Lateral deposition rate",
                   "Reach 2",   9.139827,  "Lateral deposition rate",
                   "Reach 3",  1.6654819,  "Lateral deposition rate",
                   "Reach 4",  5.2084122,  "Lateral deposition rate",
                       "All", 17.7537338,  "Lateral deposition rate"
                   )
```

Comment: Gather the two total columns into one column, and the two rate columns into another. Then you can use position ="dodge" on the bar chart.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have tried that (as shown by the dataset right at the bottom) but in the process, the line graphs end up being displayed as a bar graph which I don't want /: @iod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EroDepoGraph  <- gather(EroDepoGraph, "totalType" , "totalVal", 
  Total.lateral.erosion, Total.lateral.deposition) %>%
  gather( "rateType" , "rateVal",Lateral.erosion.rate, 
  Lateral.deposition.rate )
EroDepoStuff$Reach<-factor(EroDepoStuff$Reach)
ggplot(EroDepoStuff,aes(x=as.numeric(Reach))) +
    geom_bar(aes(y=totalVal,fill=totalType),position="dodge",stat="identity") +
    geom_line(aes(y=rateVal*10,colour=rateType))+ 
    geom_point(aes(y=rateVal*10,colour=rateType)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(name="Reach", breaks=1:5, labels=levels(EroDepoStuff$Reach))
```

[image: result]

Note that for the geom_line to work the x axis has to be continuous, hence changing it to factor and then using as.numeric(Reach) to define the x axis in ggplot. You tried to get over this by overriding it with including `group=4` in the `aes()` call, but then you also override the grouping for everything else, which causes the problem you experienced.

Comment: hi, thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion but the graphs still overlap :( and the erosion/deposition rate shows up as a single line instead of two :(

Comment: Added code for the plot with sample result (didn't add all the theme stuff included in your sample code). Note that for the geom_line to work the x axis has to be continuous, hence changing it to factor and then using `as.numeric(Reach)` to define the x axis in ggplot. Honestly, I don't even know how you got lines in your original plot...